# How can I catch an arbitrary string between defined words using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I catch an arbitrary string between defined words using regular expressions in .Net, e.g. @”…DEFINED_WORD1 some_arbitrary_string DEFINED_WORD2…”? Unfortunately my experiments with “(?=)” and other patterns are unsuccessful :(

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions?  Couldn't you accomplish the same thing using repeated calls to `IndexOf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will catch anything between the words, as long as there's a space after the first word and before the second. If there are multiple occurrences of `WORD2` after `WORD1`, the first one will be considered.

```
WORD1 (.*?) WORD2
```

This is the same, but doesn't require spaces (e.g. `"WORD1, some string WORD2"` will match):

```
WORD1\b(.*?)\bWORD2
```

This will start from the first `WORD1` and go on until the last `WORD2`:

```
WORD1\b(.*)\bWORD2
```

Depending on the details of your case, this may be cleaner and easier without regular expressions.

Comment: @digEmAll: Only the last Regex will do this. The first two use lazy matching to return only "xxx" for the first match.

Comment: @digEmAll: There are 3 regexes in this post, each of which specifies how it matches. The first two would return `xxx` and `yyy` (with/without spaces) while the last one would return `xxx WORD2 WORD1 yyy`, which is clearly explained in the post.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've looked in a hurry I didn't notice the "?" ;) Comment deleted

Answer (score 2):

```
"A(.*?)Z"
```

This would capture strings between `"A"` and `"Z"` into group 1.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Grouping and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)